# Low bandwidth Voice over IP (VoIP) software or service

Tags: voip, bandwidth

Traveling, it often happens that you find a very slow and/or unstable internet connection but you still want to communicate with people outside your room.
I am interested in a computer-computer or computer-android or android-android system. I don't want to broadcast classical music but just voice, so even if the quality is low as an old  coin telephone, that would be good enough!

Googling around, `Skype` was the most suggested option. But, I don't know if it is just placebo, but recently Skype seems to become rather heavy on bandwidth. In any case, I find only results from 5 to 10 years ago... a geological era from voip perspective.  Nowadays even a web-browser (e.g `Firefox` with  `Hello`) has a built in voip functionality (*to me, it seems heavy as well*). Somewhere I read that I need different codecs, but, frankly, I  didn't understand it.

### Desired features

- Low Bandwidth flux
- 1 to 1 VoIP would be enough
- If the connection fall, then it reconnects quickly
- No need of webcam (if not super-light)
- (opt.) Linux friendly

I could even install my own server, if necessary

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell how well it would meet *all* your requirements – but **[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/)** might be a good match. It supports the [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) protocol, and thus can be used with many providers and even self-hosted solutions. I basically use it when abroad for calls home using my VoIP provider. It worked well even in hotel rooms with barely 2 bars WiFi – which might come close to your conditions.

Trying to match your requirements:

- **Low Bandwidth flux:** Seems to work pretty well in "not optimal conditions"
- **1 to 1 VoIP would be enough:** That's definitely possible.
- **If the connection fall, then it reconnects quickly:** I must skip this part; can't remember having experienced that.
- **No need of webcam (if not super-light):** Well, *Linphone* is said to have very good video quality – and can be used for video calls. I'd not exactly call it *super* light, but it's not heavy either.
- **(opt.) Linux friendly:** it's available cross-platform: Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Mac OS, iPhone, Android, Windows Phone – see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linphone)

Also see [other answers recommending Linphone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=linphone).

Besides: The company behind *Linphone* also offers a free SIP service which you can use.