# p2p video calls (conferencing) on android

Tags: android, video-conferencing

I wanted an alternative to skype for video calls for android. Have read some articles, however, "advertised" viber and telegram do not support video now.

In this question [Video call to iPhone (FaceTime) via Windows, Android, or web](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26985/video-call-to-iphone-facetime-via-windows-android-or-web) , https://apprtc.appspot.com/ was advised, I've tried and got about 4 seconds delay.

Here [Free portable instant messaging & audio/video calls for Windows, web, Android and J2ME](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18574/free-portable-instant-messaging-audio-video-calls-for-windows-web-android-an) it advised https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients.

But situation could change and I'd like to save time on trying one app after another. Please advice on now working with smallest delay p2p video calls app (no file sharing etc. needed) for android that is now free and better have variable video quality options in case of limited traffic volume mobile plan.

Comment: Pointers: [Free portable instant messaging & audio/video calls for Windows, web, Android and J2ME](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18574/185) should fit your needs, also see my answer with Linphone [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26259/185) afterwards. Not sure about "smallest delay" and such as I myself didn't try video calls ;)